# How to pass props using react router link v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

[image: index.js]

[image: App.js]

[image: questionData.js]

[image: App.js in browser]

all I am trying to do where to put `generateQuestion` function and if I put it in `App.js`
how to pass props form `App.js` to `Quiz.js`

please if you have a better implementation of routing & `generateQuestion` function feel free to leave your recommendations

Comment: You say you want to pass props to Question from App, but didn't render it there

Comment: @Dominic sorry I meant `Quiz.js`

Comment: Why don't you use redux-saga or react-toolkit ? Pure react not a good solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `generateQuestion` callback is asynchronous, so you won't be able to send data in route state via the `Link`, but what you can do is move the `onClick` handler to the `Link` and call `event.preventDefault` on the `click` event to prevent the navigation action, and issue an imperative navigation after the questions have been fetched.

Example:

```
import { Link, useNavigate } = 'react-router-dom';

...

const navigate = useNavigate();

...

generateQuestions = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  try {
    const data = await questionsData();
    const arrData = data.map(element => ({
      ...element,
      id: nanoid(),
    }));

    navigate("/quiz", { state: { questions: arrData } });
  } catch(error) {
    // handle rejected Promise/error/etc...
  }
}

...

<Link to="/quiz" onClick={generateQuestions}>
  <button type="button">
    Start Quiz
  </button>
</Link>
...
```

In the `Quiz` component use the `useLocation` hook to access the passed route state.

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const { state } = useLocation();
const { questions } = state || {};
```

Answer (score 1):

For future questions I recommend that you actually write the code instead of pasting a picture so that it's easier to try and answer you.

That aside, I had a similar situation, what I did was the following
(Keep in mind that `item.document` is the property of the data that you want to pass through)

**Where you are getting the data** in my case I created a new class:

```
const GetData: React.FunctionComponent<{}> = () => { 
const [information, setInformation] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
.
.
//all the request stuff for getting the data
.
.
}

return (
    <div>
        {information.map((item) => (
            <div key={item.id}>
                <Link to="/yourUrl" state={{from:'test', 
                body:`${item.document}`}}> 
                    <div>
                        <h3 >{item.name}</h3>
                        <p>{item.description}</p>
                    </div>
                </Link>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
);
}
```

Remember that .map is in case you want to dynamically creat  components depending on the data that you're getting.

**Where you want to see and use the data passed**:

```
const Impementation: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
const location = useLocation()
const [itemData, setItemData] = React.useState({
   body: '',
})
.
.
.
useEffect(() => {
   .
   .
   .
   if (location.state) {
     let _state = location.state as any
     setItemData(_state)
   }, [itemData]);
   .
   .
   .
 };
```

What you did was set the state with the data that came through and then you can use it as you would use states.

This video helped me a lot
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLwR7fTB_NM&t=689s